# LoadError - cannot open shared object file - file is present, but it says no such file

Tags: ruby

Ruby comes up with `LoadErrors` I do not understand. It complains about opening a shared object file, while it's present.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
LoadError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

but `ls /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so`
returns the file `/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so`

Load Path:

```
irb(main):001:0> pp $LOAD_PATH
["/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0",
 "/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux"]
```

Another example, with the `rails` gem installed, generating a new project fails with following `LoadError`.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so (LoadError)
```

And again, doing `ls /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so` shows the presence of the file.

my ruby version is `ruby 2.3.1p112`.
In case you wonder, `uname -m` returns `x86_64`.

I must miss something obvious, I guess. Any hints popping up are much appreciated!

Comment: Run `ldd /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so`. You are probably missing libraries that the shared objects are linked against.

Comment: Thank you for your comment jordanm, that pointed me in the right direction :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65000467/12544391, e.g. adding `gem "ffi"` to `Gemfile` fixes it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to jordanm's comment, I was able to solve the issue!

The issue was related to `openssl`. `ldd` prints shared object dependencies and revealed the missing libraries.

```
ldd /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
...
libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
...
```

After installing `openssl-1.0` package, (while `openssl` v1.1.0 package was installed), the output of the same command looks better:

```
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007faddac8f000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fadda814000)
```

and now, I'm able to `require 'openssl'` as well as generating a new `rails` project.

But after all, shouldn't ruby complain about missing packages, or should `openssl-1.0` be at least a dependency of `rails`?

Comment: Gem dependencies can not expressly depend on system packages/libraries, but they will fail to compile in cases when the relevant system libraries don't exist. I suspect that openssl was installed when you setup the ruby environment but was removed later.

Comment: You're right, I was cleaning up my system and removed some packages. `openssl-1.0` was properly removed, as a dependency of a package I removed. Thanks for the explanation :)