# AWS EC2 CenterOS : libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, libssl, libcrypto

I hope there will be a warrior.

I'm deploying my rails project on AWS EC2.

System type: **Cent OS**

ERROR:

```
brew install mysql
```

I'm using linuxbrew to install mysql but it gives me
make error

I installed rvm, rails, mysql(using yum not brew)...
The disaster is from now...

```
rails db:migrate

require': libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

I wasted 3 days for this error.
Please help me...

Comment: What Distro are you on?

Comment: Either way you may need the libssl packages, if you're using yum, try `sudo yum install libssl-dev`

Comment: Linux. Thank you for quick reply.But it gives me...
No package libssl-dev available.

Comment: `yum install openssl` if you already have it, then do `yum reinstall openssl`

Comment: Thank you but, it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it.
I can't sure exactly but when you install openssl using brew,
the path is here:

```sh
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/
```

So, I have to use this here

```sh
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

Thank you all!!!!!

GOOD DAY!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `GKE`, you need `libssl` packages. I think somehow your box is missing the symlink.

Try:

```
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

This should fix the problem. If it doesn't, you might have to create symlinks manually by:

```
cd /usr/lib64

sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

---

Simillar question - [LoadError - cannot open shared object file - file is present, but it says no such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163676/loaderror-cannot-open-shared-object-file-file-is-present-but-it-says-no-suc)

Comment: Thank you but when I run `sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10` and it shows `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘libssl.so.10’: File exists`  In fact, I checked libssl.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.10 from /usr/lib64 and I could see that libssl.so.10 exists but libssl.so.1.0.0 doesn't exist before. Could you help?